# Regex expression for sublists

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary, sublist

I have a list of lists such as:

```
my_list = [['aaa_house', 'aaa_car', 'aaa_table'], ['aaa_love', 'aaa_hate', 'aaa_life']]

desired_result = [['house', 'car', 'table'], ['love', 'hate', 'life']]
```

I am using regex expression to filter the desired strings.

**I tried:**

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\baaa[_]')
[pattern.search(i).group(1) for i in lista_fim]
```

**I tried**

```
def find_fims(sublist):
    pattern = re.compile(r'\baaa_')
    return [pattern.search(i).group(1) for i in sublist]


answer = map(find_fims, lista_with_sublists)
```

I could not get any results using this. How could I apply a function to a sublist of a list but keeping my sublist format? I would just like to get the right names of my sub list.

Any help?

Comment: Looks like you can use `str.split("_")[1]`

Comment: my real case situation requires regex because it is not just this

Comment: Or may be slicing str[4:]?

Comment: Use `[pattern.sub('', i) for i in lista_fim]`. Your pattern matches what you want to discard, and you are using it to extract (what you do not need)

Comment: @may Please provide your actual input then. As it is splitting with `_` will suffice.

Comment: @may I think there are some clarifications needed regarding your list: Is it: `[['aaa_house', 'aaa_car', 'aaa_table'], ['aaa_love', 'aaa_hate', 'aaa_life']]` or `[['aaa_house, aaa_car, aaa_table'], ['aaa_love, aaa_hate, aaa_life']]`?

Comment: @kerwei done! they are all strings the elements of sublist

Comment: Use: [[re.findall(r'aaa_(\w+)', i)[0]  for i in j] for j in my_list] to get output: [['house', 'car', 'table'], ['love', 'hate', 'life']]

Comment: @mamun your solution works with the following change [[re.findall(r'aaa_(\w+)', i) for i in j] for j in lista_with_sublists]

Comment: @mamun you can post as an answer to this question! thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern matches what you want to discard, and you are using it to extract (what you do not need). So, all you need is to use `re.sub`:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'\baaa_')
my_list = [['aaa_house', 'aaa_car', 'aaa_table'], ['aaa_love', 'aaa_hate', 'aaa_life']]
print([[pattern.sub('', i) for i in y] for y in my_list])
```

Output:

```
[['house', 'car', 'table'], ['love', 'hate', 'life']]
```

[See the Python demo](https://ideone.com/N3mXM7) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RKFX73/1).

**NOTE** If you want to match `aaa` at the *start of a string*, replace `\b` with `^`.  See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RKFX73/2).

Note you do not need to put `_` inside a character class, `_` is not a special regex metacharacter and there is little sense in putting a single word char into a character class (this construct is meant to be filled with multiple chars, or char ranges).

Comment: thank you! your explanation is very clear and easy to understand!

Comment: @may Note that in the example you provided in the question, `aaa` appears to be both at the start of the string and at the beginning of a word. If you meant to match `aaa` at the start of the string only, you should use `^aaa_` (or `^a{3}_` if it is still readbale for you)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following pattern:

```
(\w)\1+_(\w+)
```

- (\w)\1+ matches the repetitive string that you want to discard e.g. aaa
- (\w+) captures the target word under Group 2

You will have to use Group 2 instead of 1 though.

Comment: where should the pattern aaa_ will be written in this example?

Comment: (\w)\1+ is the generalized form. (\w) captures a word character under Group 1 and the quantifier after that '\1+' tells it to match the same character in Group 1 at least once and as many times as necessary

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
out_list = [[re.findall(r'aaa_(\w+)', i)[0] for i in j] for j in lista_with_sublists] 

#output: 

out_list = [['house', 'car', 'table'], ['love', 'hate', 'life']]
```